# Can Someone explain time signatures?

Tags: time-signatures

What is mean by 3/4, 6/8, 4/4 etc.?
Some times T get confuse about how to choose time signature in DAW.

Comment: Hi Rahul - does https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/65093/what-can-one-do-to-understand-time-signatures answer your question?

Comment: Suggest you read the 'related' questions and answers to the right of your screen. They probably go deeper than you need, but that's not a bad thing.